# Mongo transactions and updates

Tags: mongodb

If I've got an environment with multiple instances of the same client connecting to a MongoDB server and I want a simple locking mechanism to ensure single client access for a short time, can I safely use my own lock object?

Say I have one object with a lockState that can be "locked" or "unlocked" and the plan is everyone checks that it is "unlocked" before doing "stuff". To lock the system I say:

`db.collection.update( { "lockState": "unlocked" },   { "lockState": "locked" })`

(aka `UPDATE lockObj SET lockState = 'locked' WHERE lockState = 'unlocked'`)

**If two clients try to lock the system at the same time, is it possible that both clients can end up thinking they "have the lock"?**

- Both clients find the record by the query parameter of the update
- Client 1 updates the record (which is an atomic operation)

  - update returns success
- Client 2 updates the document (it's already found it before client 1 modified it)

  - update returns success

I realize this is probably a very contrived case that would be very hard to reproduce, but is it possible or does mongo somehow make client 2's update fail?

***Alternative approach***
Use insert instead of update. insert is atomic and will fail if the document already exists.

To lock the system: `db.locks.insert({someId: 27, state: “locked”})`.
If the insert succeeds - I've got the lock and since the update was atomic, no one else can have it.
If the insert fails - someone else must have the lock.

Comment: Wait, are you drilling your db down from multihread to single thread on purpose? That's what the first paragraph says...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If two clients try to lock the system at the same time, is it possible that both clients can end up thinking they "have the lock"?

No, only one client at a time writes to the lock space (Global, Database, Collection or Document depending on your version and configuration) and the operations on that lock space are sequential and one or the other (read or write, not both) per document so that other connections will not mistakenly pick up a document in a inbetween state and think that it is not locked by another client.

All operations on a single document are atomic, whether update or insert.

Comment: Thanks @Sammaye - to shrink that back to it's simplest form: "the update (query + modify) is atomic"?

Comment: @John3136 indeed, per document, for a multie document update will not over the entire update but will over each document it passes